# Cascading dropdownlists in browser-enabled form

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu, infopath

Im trying to fill a dropdownlist based on an other one:
Departments and SubDepartments.

i followed this link: http://www.sharepoint-tips.com/2007/01/infopath-form-services-implementing.html

when i try to fill in a form it gives me an error: 
Request Failed (--> securityException) on this line: 
q.FileLocation = q.FileLocation + "&FilterField1=Department&FilterValue1=" + GetDepartmentValue();
and the second dropdownlist (subdepartments) is not filtered.

Any idea what might be the problem?

Comment: Are your data connections to SharePoint as in the example? What is the code in GetDeparmentValue?

Comment: I don't think that you can do cascasding dropdown lists on browser enabled forms.